# DataTables Sort Not Working: What Could Be the Issue?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I have this table error when i tried to Sort the data using sort fiture by datatables it just change the 1st line of data and the other data stay the same as it is doesnt get sorted at all, and because this error it messed up many thing such as download file from some id that make all the data share the same id even thought it shouldnt. so here's an example of my datatables code

```
<table id="datatablesSimple">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Username</th>
                                    <th>Nama</th>
                                    <th>Identitas</th>
                                    <th>Kelola</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <?php
                                    $no = 1;
                                    $data = mysqli_query($koneksi, "select * from user Order by identitas ASC");
                                    while ($d = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
                                    ?>
                                        <td><?php echo $d['username']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $d['nama']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo ucwords($d['identitas']); ?></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <center>
                                                <?php
                                                echo '<div class="data-item">';
                                                echo '<button class="btn btn-primary edit-btn fas fa-pen-to-square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" data-username="' . $d['username'] . '">Edit</button>';
                                                echo '<button class="btn btn-danger delete-btn fas fa-trash" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteConfirmationModal" data-username="' . $d['username'] . '">Hapus</button>';
                                                echo '</div>';
                                                ?>

                                                <!-- Delete Confirmation Modal -->
                                                <div class="modal fade" id="deleteConfirmationModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Confirm Deletion</h5>
                                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                                </button>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                                Apa anda yakin ingin menghapus data ini ?
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                                                <a id="deleteLink" href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </center>
                                        </td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php
                                    }
                            ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

here's an image for the error example

[Image 1](https://imgur.com/h7JQwuw)
[Image 2](https://imgur.com/3AZSvRd)

Thanks.

i've tried modifying the table to some extent, and i've tried to change the library etc.

Comment: It looks to me like your `<table>` HTML is malformed. You seem to have just one `<tr>` tag at the top of the table, when it should be at the start of each row. Move it inside your `while` loop.

Comment: here's an update, i found the problem is because the edit button and delete button is at the same cells, while i tried to erase 1 button it worked normally or i tried to separate the cells it worked normally too, i dont know why tho? can anyone explain to me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By following code and ensuring that your DataTables setup is correct, you should be able to resolve the sorting and related issues in your DataTable. try following java script function for sort:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatablesSimple').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [
            { targets: [3], orderable: false } // Disable sorting for the "Kelola" column
        ]
    });
});
```